# regarding operator / to generate integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

After inputting an image file, which is represented as a multi-dimensional array, e.g., of shape `(300,300)` The values for each entry range from 0 to 255.

In order to transform it to gray scale, I use `img = img/255`, or in other words, I want each pixel value to be either 0 or 1. I am not sure whether this `img/255` is the right way to do it? Can the operator `/` enforce the result value to be integer 0, or 1. I tried `int(img/255)`, which gives me the error message. The usage of `img/255` works, but the python document does not say that `/` will ensure to generate the integer value, like floor operation. That's why I am not very confident here.

Comment: If using Python 3.x, I think you should use img//255 (floor division).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image of 0 and 1s will not be grayscale but black and white
If the image is a numy array you can use around(img/255) or floor, depending on the wanted behaviour. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around